# Skipped "XXX": secret key not available

Tags: git, gnupg

gpg4win-3.1.0 gpg:

[image]

I have tried many methods. But it didn't work.
I have my key ID. 
I did this.

`$ git config --global user.signingkey XXXXXXX`

I wanted to change my gpg.program.
But I have no gpg2.exe.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post console output or code directly and don't use images. What problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just solved the problem.When I setted gpg.program gpg.exe, it works.

Comment: So go ahead and post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the gpg.exe. My path is C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe.
Set the gpg.program.

```
$ git config –global gpg.program “C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe”
```

Then set the signingkey in Git Bash.

```
$ git config user.signingkey [GPG key ID]
```